# How to fix 'constructor cannot be applied to given types' error in Java?

Tags: java, constructor

I was making a class of functions to be performed on complex numbers. When I create a new object I get the following error:

> error: constructor ComplexNumbers in class ComplexNumbers cannot be
>   applied to given types; ComplexNumbers c1 = new ComplexNumbers(real1,
>   imaginary1);
>                             ^   required: no arguments   found: int,int   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>
> error: constructor ComplexNumbers in class ComplexNumbers cannot be
>   applied to given types;       ComplexNumbers c2 = new
>   ComplexNumbers(real2, imaginary2);
>                             ^   required: no arguments   found: int,int   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>
> 2 errors

**Code from main**

```
    int real1 = s.nextInt();
    int imaginary1 = s.nextInt();

    int real2 = s.nextInt();
    int imaginary2 = s.nextInt();

    ComplexNumbers c1 = new ComplexNumbers(real1, imaginary1);
    ComplexNumbers c2 = new ComplexNumbers(real2, imaginary2);
```

**Constructor code**

```
public void ComplexNumbers(int real, int imaginary){
    this.real=real;
    this.imaginary=imaginary;
    return;
}
```

Comment: a constructor has no return type. the posted code should not pass compilation

Comment: *public void ComplexNumbers* is not a constrcutor

Comment: in addition - constructor isn't defined with `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what a constructor will look like for `ComplexNumbers` with two **int** parameters:

```
public ComplexNumbers(int real, int imaginary){
}
```

Comment: According to the guidelines ... Comments are not for answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment